# To find $\text{Res}\left(\sin\left(\frac{z}{z-1}\right),1\right)$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, residue-calculus

I have to find $\text{Res}\left(\sin\left(\frac{z}{z-1}\right),1\right)$

We have $$\sin\left(\frac{z}{z-1}\right) = \sin\left(1+\frac{1}{z-1}\right)\\= \left(1+\frac{1}{z-1}\right)-\frac{1}{3!}\left(1+\frac{1}{z-1}\right)^3+\frac{1}{5!}\left(1+\frac{1}{z-1}\right)^5 - \frac{1}{7!}\left(1+\frac{1}{z-1}\right)^7 + \cdots$$

Therefore, we have 
$$\text{Res}\left(\sin\left(\frac{z}{z-1}\right),1\right)=1-\frac{1}{3!}\binom{3}{1}+\frac{1}{5!}\binom{5}{1}-\frac{1}{7!}\binom{7}{1}+ \cdots \\ = 1-\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{4!}-\frac{1}{6!}+ \cdots = \cos1$$

**Alternate Proof**

$$\sin\left(1+\frac{1}{z-1}\right) = \sin1 \cos\left(\frac{1}{z-1}\right) + \cos1 \sin\left(\frac{1}{z-1}\right)$$

We will get a $1/(z-1)$ term only in the expansion of $\sin\left(\frac{1}{z-1}\right)$, therefore the residue is $\cos1$

Am I right?

Comment: I don’t think so. Doesn’t this function have an essential singularity at $z=1$? Have you sketched the graph?

Comment: Yes, but my calculations don't say otherwise

Comment: @junkquill that being said, usually residues arent defined at essential singularities... we define residues only for meromorphic functions. Why are you attempting to calculate a residue here?

Comment: It was a question posed during a class test for this Complex Analysis course I'm taking. But I've read that residues are defined for essential singularities as well

Comment: But the Residue is the coefficient of the $1/(z-1)$ term, which only the expansion of $\sin$ has

Comment: Your proof seems correct to me. Since Laurent series are absolutely convergent, we may reorder it in any way and still get the same sum, so the coefficient that multiplies $1/(z-1)$ may be calculated this way.

Comment: Your proof is right in both ways......